# Как я могу посмотреть передаваемые байты по протоколу Bluetooth?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, c, сокет

Спустя почти полтора года я снова решил вернуться к этому вопросу.

У меня стоит задача: отслеживать нажатые клавиши на беспроводных наушниках, и при получении определенного пакета - выполнять уже какое-то действие в коде.

Чтоб подойти к решению этой задачи, прежде я хочу выводить все пакеты в консоль с помощью `Python3` или же `C/C++` (предпочтительнее 1 вариант).

Как я могу получить эти пакеты именно в коде с помощью `Python/C/C++`? То есть это НЕ должна быть команда для терминала в стиле `os.system('hcitool ...')`, а именно исходник.

А методом "тыка" я уже смогу определить, какой пакет отвечает за нажатые клавиши на беспроводных наушниках.

Также я пытался использовать `Wireshark` (Windows), но к слову, ни один пакет он не уловил.

Я предполагаю, что можно создать соединение через `Python3` и модуль `socket` на `Linux`:

`socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)`, и затем уже выводить пакеты для анализа.

Не обязательно показывать код (но было бы неплохо посмотреть на минимально воспроизводимый пример на `Python3`). Хотя бы просто направьте в правильную сторону, где я смогу почитать об этом. К слову, я искал в интернете и вот СОВСЕМ не обнаружил толковых результатов.

Comment: А ОСь какая у вас? Под виндой?

Comment: Хм... все запутано... на хабре есть идея http://habr.com/ru/post/417303/ проверяется sndrec быстро. Не могу проверить. Запись звука с безпроводных наушников можно сделать. Если это не сработает - нужно что б дрова поддерживали проброс сигнала кнопки - и смотреть что там в дрова зашили.

Comment: @nick_n_a, спасибо хоть за какую-то информацию, но этот пост я уже находил(

Comment: ушники спарены с компьютером? какая ось то?

Comment: @eri - да, наушники спарены. Из всего того, что мне удалось сделать на данный момент - получить ответ   `AT+BRSF=191`, я в свою очередь подал команду - `AT+BRSF:20\r\r\nOK\r\n`, после этого я подаю еще какие-то команды, и на этом скрипт замирает. Я так понимаю, что это режим конфигурации, и мне вряд ли удастся получить желаемый результат. Ось - Kali Linux 2021.1. На виндовс десятке бессмысленно запускать - кажется, не поддерживается какой-то из протоколов (но с этим не уверен)

Comment: на линукс кнопки легко слушаются через hid

Comment: @eri, да, это примерно то что я искал!!! Я попробовал получать данные через `evdev` - пока что получаю результат только с одной кнопки, другие 2 пока не работают - буду разбираться. Возможно есть какие-то другие модули помимо `evdev`? Посмотрел еще в интернете - есть `pyserial`. Я так понимаю, она тоже подойдет для моей задачи? И я так понимаю - hid можно прослушать и на винде? Оставьте какой-то ответ, чтобы я мог назначить награду)

Comment: И у меня появился еще один вопрос - если я слушаю через hid, то получаю информацию только ввода-вывода. А как я могу получить полный список передаваемых пакетов в коде?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полный список передаваемых данных можно получить через pcap. Получишь обмен с hid, pulseaudio в сыром виде.

Чтоб поговорить с устройвом используется интерфейс HCI. В питоне это продвинутей всего сделать можно через scapy https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layers/bluetooth.html . Также там интегрирован pcap снифер. Все данные распарсены в классы.

А события кнопок на подключенном устройстве можно получить перехватив их как обычные кнопки evdev. Bluez транслирует их как медиаклавиши. У меня ловятся все 5.